# How to stop a user selecting a DropDown option without 'disabling' it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

**Question Background:**

I have two `dropdown` menus in my app. One is to allow a user to select a Minimum monetary selection and the other a Maximum monetary selection.

**The Issue:**

If a user selects a value in the Minimum dropdown i.e **4** that is larger than the value select in the Maximum dropdown lets say **3** as then I want to display a popup dialog to the user informing them they cannot do this and then stop the clicked item in the minimum dropdown from being selected.

I can see plenty of example using:

```
.disable
```

but I do do not want to 'grey out' any options just validate the clicked items each time and then stop the item from being selected.

**Is this possible?** Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I would simply modify the models of the two dropdowns. IE. once the user selects 4 in the min dropdown, the values in the max dropdown start at 4 (or even 5). and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "change" event on the select menu to check the value and then decide what to do with this.

```
document.getElementById('your_dropdown_id').addEventListener('change', myfct);
```

Where "myfct" is the function testing the value.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
var validate = true;
if ( FirstSelectedValue > SecondSelectedValue ){
alert('first selected value must be higher or equal to second value');
validate = false;
}
```

//whereever you pass the information to..

```
if (validate && your other options..){
//continue, first value is lower or equal to second value..
}
```

A better option would be to only populate the second value when the first value have been selected and only allow valid options.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this programmatically by handling clicks on the dropdown manually. For example:

```
$('.dropdown-min').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if($(e.target).val() < $('.dropdown-max').find(":selected").val()) {
  $(e.target).attr('selected', 'selected');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vgq5sLd3/3/)

```js
// grab the two dropdowns with their classname on change event
$('.min-max').on('change', function() {
  var $th = $(this),
    id = $th.attr('id');

  // pass the id and the value to the function
  updateMinMax(id, parseInt($th.val()));
})

function updateMinMax(id, v) {

  // determine the id of the other dropdown
  var otherID = (id == 'minimum') ? 'maximum' : 'minimum',
    thisDropdown = $('#' + id),
    otherDropdown = $('#' + otherID);

  // we need to make sure the other dropdown value is set so we need
  // to add this condition otherDropdown.val() != ''
  if (id == 'minimum' && otherDropdown.val() != '' && thisDropdown.val() > otherDropdown.val()) {
    // if a selected value from minimum dropdown is MORE than
    // the selected maximum value
    alert('minimum cannot be greater than maximum');
    // reset current dropdown selection
    thisDropdown.val('');
  } else if (id == 'maximum' && otherDropdown.val() != '' && thisDropdown.val() < otherDropdown.val()) {
    // if a selected value from maximum dropdown is LESS than
    // the selected minimum value
    alert('maximum cannot be less than minimum');
    thisDropdown.val('');
  }
}
```

```css
select{width:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Min:<select class="min-max" id="minimum">
  <option></option><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option></select><hr>
Max:<select class="min-max" id="maximum">
  <option></option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option></select>
```